# Finding Element on a webapplication built using frames

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java with Selenium Webdriver. I am currently writing a script to verify a contact has been added to a contact list from a form. The workflow is:

The menu of our application uses Angular js while the rest is a frame.

Once I click on the menu I need "contacts", 
I then switch to frame, to interact with the objects in the iframe, 
I click on the list I would like to open, and within the frame, the page loads the the list of contacts. The issue I am having, once the list is loaded, the webdriver no longer can find the elements within the list.

**source code:**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%">
    <!--

     HEADER 

    -->
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <!--

         CONTENT 

        -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" height="*">
                <div id="listDetails" style="width: 958px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); height: 694px;">
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
                        <!--

                         BEGIN HEADER 

                        -->
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="background: url(../image/msn/table_heading.png) bottom left repeat-x"></tr>
                            <!--

                             END HEADER 

                            -->
                            <!--

                             BEGIN DATA ROWS 

                            -->
                            <tr class="rowEven" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#FFFFCC'" style="">

<td nowrap="" align="left" style=" border-bottom: #DDDDDD dotted 1px; color: #666666; cursor:pointer; padding-right: 10px" onclick="openContact ('l-sf-lead-1f26:0')"></td>
```

**My Code:**

```
    String tableHeader = "//*[@id='listDetails']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]";

    WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
    WebElement pwField =driver.findElement(By.id("pw"));
    WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton"));
    //assertTrue("checking site title", driver.getTitle().startsWith("Act-On :: Login"));

    //Logging in -> to new ui.
    emailField.sendKeys(aoEmailtomcat8);
    pwField.sendKeys(password);
    loginBtn.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.navigate().to(newUI_URL);
    Thread.sleep(4000);

    //Clicks on Contacts Menu
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(contactsMenu)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(marketignListMenu)).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame("content");
    Thread.sleep(4000);

    //Clicks on List
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(defaultList)).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(fistItemList)).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    //Does not locate the element, FAILS!
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(tableHeader));
```

Comment: Instead of thread.sleep , please use explicit wait to until element detect.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your frame html code.

Make sure your driver is switching to frame successfully. Is **Content** your frame name? You can switch to frame using three different ways.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(<frame name>);
driver.switchTo().frame(<frame index>); // Zero- based index
driver.switchTo().frame(<frame element>); // use driver.findElement method to find the frame first and pass as a parameter
```

As @Helping Hands said never use `Thread.Sleep`, use `WebDriverWait` to wait until page or element loads.